# How to set up remix.ethereum.org and my GitHub repo

Tags: ide, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to set up my GitHub repo at https://github.com/denismp/solidity.git to work with the remix.ethereum.org IDE.  I have followed the instructions at https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html, but when I try to activate the remixd plugin, it indicates that I need to make sure the remixd is running, which it is.

According to the instructions, "remixd provides full read and write access to the given folder for any application that can access the TCP port 65520 on your localhost."  Do I need to do something to add the 65520 port?

```
    /Users/denisputnam/git/solidity>remixd -s /Users/denisputnam/git/solidity --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org
[WARN] You may now only use IDE at https://remix.ethereum.org to connect to that instance
[WARN] Any application that runs on your computer can potentially read from and write to all files in the directory.
[WARN] Symbolinc links are not forwarded to Remix IDE

setup notifications for /Users/denisputnam/git/solidity
Sun Jan 19 2020 14:20:02 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) Remixd is listening on 127.0.0.1:65520
```

Comment: I got it to work on firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve the problem.

Make sure that you have the full developer version of Xcode.app installed. As a precaution, go to the app store and install it regardless. Follow the instructions.

The goal is to get the remixd installed, but it needs the Xcode developer installed to do that.

The following websites will have the instructions, but I condensed them below in the steps.

Talks about the gyp install and the xcode-select comands:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md

Talks about node-gyp and node-gyp-install:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569

Has the instruction for the online IDE locahost setup:
https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html

Has the dmg to install on MAC:
https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases

1. npm install -g node-gyp-install
2. sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
3. xcodebuild -version
4. npm install -g remixd
5. install the dmg file.
6. remixd -s /Users/denisputnam/git/solidity --remix-ide package://a7df6d3c223593f3550b35e90d7b0b1f.mod

In step 5. you will set it up for the online web IDE. Once you get the remix.app installed, activate the remix plugin from the plugins list. When it tries to connect to your local file system, you will get something like:

Sun Jan 19 2020 15:49:17 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) Connection from origin package://a7df6d3c223593f3550b35e90d7b0b1f.mod rejected.

Copy the "package://a7df6d3c223593f3550b35e90d7b0b1f.mod ".

Stop the remixd with Ctrl-C.

Then restart it with something like:

remixd -s /Users/denisputnam/git/solidity --remix-ide package://a7df6d3c223593f3550b35e90d7b0b1f.mod

Now the remixd will point to your local remix IDE rather than the online IDE.

So why do all this? So that you can create a repo in your own github account, clone it to your local file system, and then hookup your local remix IDE to use your local github repo. This will allow you to check in code to github.